# Laravel array_push

Tags: laravel, foreach

This is my data:

```
$dataItems = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'serial' => "XXXXXXAA1",
        'pd_item_info' =>
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'quantity' => 5,
            'ipo_item_pml_info' => 
            [
                'id' => 1,
                'product_name' => 'Keyboard'
            ]
        ]
    ], 
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'serial' => "XXXXXXAA2",
        'pd_item_info' =>
        [
            'id' => 2,
            'quantity' => 10,
            'ipo_item_pml_info' => 
            [
                'id' => 2,
                'product_name' => 'Keyboard'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

and I need to have this output:

```
$output = [
    'product_name' => "Keyboard",
    'serial' =>["XXXXXXAA1", "XXXXXXAA2"]
];
```

Using `foreach` and `array_push` in laravel, how can I merge duplicate `product_name` and join there serial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume `pd_item_info` and `ipo_item_pml_info` always there

first distiguish the array key based on product name and all the serial key is append under same product name

```
foreach($dataItems as $item) {
    $products[$item['pd_item_info']['ipo_item_pml_info']['product_name']][] = $item['serial'];
}

//output
// [
//     'Keyboard' => ['XXXXXXAA1', 'XXXXXXAA2'];
// ]
```

next, formatting according to your needed

```
foreach($products as $key => $product) {
    $output[] = [
        'product_name' => $key,
        'serial' => $product
    ];
}
```

Thats it.. =D